# FFmpegのconcatをつかっても4つ以上の動画ファイルが連結できない

Tags: ffmpeg

#### 質問内容

FFmpegのオプションで複数のファイルを連結するfilter`concat`がありますが、そのオプションをつかって1コマンドで20ファイル連結させようと試みたのですが、3ファイルまでしか連結されません。入力ファイルの形式、コマンドに間違い、もしくはそういった制約があるのでしょうか...？

#### 実施したこと

1.画像から動画ファイルを作成
`ffmpeg -r 1 -i img000.png -vf format=yuv420p video_part000.mp4`
`ffmpeg -r 1 -i img001.png -vf format=yuv420p video_part001.mp4`
....
`ffmpeg -r 1 -i img019.png -vf format=yuv420p video_part019.mp4`

※ 入力ファイル情報
`ffprobe video_part000.mp4`

```
{
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_part000.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 141 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 532x366, 134 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn, 2 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/2",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 532,
            "height": 366,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 21,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 4,
            "is_avc": "1",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "1/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "1/1",
            "time_base": "1/16384",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 16384,
            "duration": "1.000000",
            "bit_rate": "134600",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "1",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2.
`ffmpeg -i video_part000.mp4 -i video_part001.mp4 ... -i video_part019.mp4 -filter_complex "concat=n=20:v=1:a=0" -vcodec libx264 output000.mp4`

#### 実施結果

video_part000.mp4 〜 video_part002.mp4までの3ファイルまでしか連結されない

どなたかご教示いただければ、幸いに存じます。

Comment: concatについての回答ではないのですが、連番画像を動画にしたいのであれば `image2` demuxer を使った方が簡単のような気がします。 http://qiita.com/riocampos/items/2f4fe927b5cf99aff767 https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1

Comment: コメント頂き、ありがとうございます。
連番画像から同じfpsで動画をつくる方法は上記方法にていけるのは確認しているのですが、そもそもやりたいのが1枚1枚の画像の表示される時間を変化させて動画をつくりたいのです。例えば、1枚目の画像からつくった動画は1秒、2枚目の画像からつくった動画は3秒というような具合です。もしこちらの方法がわかれば、この質問のようにやる必要はないかもしれません...

Comment: [concat demuxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1)を使ってみてはいかがでしょう。[Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: シェル側でエラーは出てないでしょうか？